# Any way to detect that app have been force stop

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any way to detect that past launch have finished with force stop (terminate)? Not in the moment, just in next launch. Maybe resets someone temporary flag, state or other that can be checked. For example, I tried to check `WorkInfo` from `WorkManager`. But its requests survive after force stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the information the [`ApplicationExitInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo) provides for API 30 and higher devices. Specifically the [`REASON_USER_REQUESTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo#REASON_USER_REQUESTED):

> Application process was killed because of the user request, for example, user clicked the "Force stop" button of the application in the Settings, or removed the application away from Recents.

This is actually precisely what [WorkManager uses to detect force stops on API 30 and higher](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:work/work-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/utils/ForceStopRunnable.java;l=185) by using [`getHistoricalProcessExitReasons`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/ActivityManager#gethistoricalprocessexitreasons):

```
ActivityManager activityManager =
    (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ApplicationExitInfo> exitInfoList =
    activityManager.getHistoricalProcessExitReasons(
        null /* match caller uid */,
        0, // ignore
        0 // ignore
    );

if (exitInfoList != null && !exitInfoList.isEmpty()) {
    // The most recent exit is the first one, so we can just
    // check that one
    ApplicationExitInfo lastExit = exitInfoList.get(0);
    if (info.getReason() == REASON_USER_REQUESTED) {
        // You were force stopped, do your logic here
    }
}
```

There's no direct equivalent on lower API levels, which is why WorkManager, as per that code linked above, sets an alarm very, very far in the future simply because a force stop will clear all alarms - the lack of an alarm is enough to somewhat reliably detect a force stop.

Comment: I know that all alarms cancel after force stop. I tried to use pending intent with `FLAG_NO_CREATE` (like in their code example `isForceStopped`). When I launch app after stop - pending intent still alive (intent not null) but alarm canceled (according adb log). So I can't understand why in their case it works in lower API.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way through which you can detect the app is forced stop or not.Since every application in android has a unique process ID when force stop happen system kills the whole process leaving no trace behind.

And WorkManager only start working again if you start the application after force stop so its normal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method to check a force stop, however you can use a cloud based storage like Firebase to store a flag or state that indicates whether the app was force stopped in the last launch. This will allow you to get the information if a force stop happens.